# React com React Router / Configuração dinâmica

Tags: react, react-router

Tenho duas dúvidas sobre rotas, no escopo do meu projeto, eu teria que montar isso de acordo com o json que chega, pois pode vir com uma árvore de componente diferente.

Eu teria algo parecido com isso:

```
workflow:{
   name : intro,
   component: {
      path: /view,
      component: intro
   },
   name : help,
   component: {
      path: /view,
      component: help
   },
},
Intro : { //component
   link: '/help'
}
```

Neste contexto eu teria que montar uma sequência de passos.

---

No segundo caso, eu teria que ter um link em um botão, que faz o acionamento de uma url e mostra o obj ( este link vem no json acima, com o nome do componente )
Por exemplo, na tela de Intro, tem um botão, e ao clicar, tenho que ser "redirecionado"

Alguém saberia como fazer isso com react router?

Obrigado